# How to Generate href from razor pages using anchor tag helpers?

Tags: c#, anchor, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am using razor pages and.net 5.0
My page name is `Edit.cshtml` which has page directive url as
`@page /p/{id}`
Now from another page I want to generate put a anchor tag to this page
I know we can just do it by

```
<a href="/p/id">
```

but I want to generate it with anchor tage helper in .net lik  asp-page, asp-route

beacuse here my page name and route is different I can't generate.

Is there any other way to generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter, if your page directive differs from your page name.

If your page is called "Edit" with a route `/p/{id}` create a tag helper like this:

```html
<a asp-page="/Edit" asp-route-id="3">Click here to edit things.</a>
```

This will generate the following markup

```html
<a href="/p/3">Click here to edit things.</a>
```

Comment: In my case this gives `<a href>Click here to edit things.</a>` what can be the problem?